# SQL Query, sorting when vales are both Int and Characters

Tags: sql, sorting

I am working on a client website, we have an order form within their website that allows for them to select their Department then select products specific to their department, and lastly once they select a product they will get Quantity option. All of these fields are populated through SQL queries from one database that lists all the departments, products and quantity options.

Let me preface this by saying I am very much a beginner when it comes to SQL, this has been a little project of my own that I am working on to stream line some of our processes. So go easy on me.

The issues I am having is with sorting, I had to set the Quantity database column as a VARCHAR, since it would not just be Integers, for example some products may simply have qty options of 250, 500, 1000, but others may have qty options of 10 pads, 20 pads, 50 pads, etc.

The forms module that we are using has what I am assuming is a basic SQL Query input, as the query examples they provided were just strings of syntax, not like I have seen in some of my research trying to address this issue.

Here is the Query I have written to call back the data:

```
select distinct Quantity 
from GSD_Products 
where Form = [Form] 
order by Quantity ASC
```

so my issue is since this data is not INT when the dropdown field on the form populates for some of my products that are only INT they are not in normal ascending order:

```
1000
250
2500
500
5000
```

where I would like them to appear as:

```
250
500
1000
2500
5000
```

The other product quantities that do have a mix of int and characters are listing fine in an appropriate order, example:

10 Pads, 20 Pads, 50 Pads.

Someone did point me in the direction of possibly parsing the NVARCHAR value, and I have been trying to research on that, but my lack of knowledge is just a road block to understand what options I can try in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Your values are stored as strings, so they are sorted as strings.  One method is to convert them, something like this:

```
order by cast(Quantity as int) ASC
```

If you have to handle both numeric and non-numeric values, then another method is to order by length and value:

```
order by len(Quantity), Quantity
```

This runs no risk of type-conversion errors.

Comment: I tried both of these options and I am getting an error message:

Please specify valid sql query

I am not sure if this is because the SQL Query functions of this form are more basic and it does not allow for more complex Queries.

Comment: @JerodBrown . . . These are `ORDER BY` clauses that expect a `SELECT` and so on before them.

Answer (score 0):

I would have another field on the product table called description where you can put 'Pads'.  If the sql query controls order then you can simply concatenate the int and char columns in the control but not the order by clause.  If the control, like a combo box, controls the order then I would put only quantity in the control and then have a label next to it to display the description.

Comment: I did try this initially, but the forms module we are using does not allow for me to put any variable data or data pulling from SQL for a label. 

I am assuming there is not a way using a SQL query to combine data from 2 columns if this information was separated out? QTY and Description separate columns into QTY Description with a query.

Comment: Can you use a text box and make it read only to serve as a label?  If not that's unfortunate.  In that case it is important to know if the query controls the order of the control.  Also of note is that some form building software will allow two columns in a control like a combo box and allow you to sort on the one you choose.